# ORDER BY multiple columns, SELECT TOP in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Suppose you have a table of products. Each product has a price and a discount. Like

| productName | price | discount | region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 11 | 5 | US |
| A | 10 | 4 | EU |
| A | 10 | 1 | Asia |
| D | 50 | 6 | US |

Does anybody know how to select the lowest price (first) and at the highest discount (second)? Like

| productName | price | discount | region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 4 | EU |
| D | 50 | 6 | US |

I have to use MS Access for my query and I tried (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bcf208/1)

```sql
CREATE TABLE Product
    ([productName] varchar(5), [price] INT, [discount] INT, [region] varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO Product
    ([productName], [price], [discount], [region])
VALUES
    ('A', 11,5, 'US'),
    ('A', 10,4, 'EU'),
    ('A', 10,1, 'Asia'),
    ('D', 50,6, 'US')

SELECT A.*
FROM Product A
INNER JOIN (
SELECT top 1
  B.price,
  B.discount
FROM Product B
WHERE B.productName = A.productName 
ORDER BY B.price ASC, B.discount DESC
) B1 ON B1.price = A.price AND B1.discount = A.discount

-- Error: The multi-part identifier "A.productName" could not be bound.
```

Comment: The title says MS SQL, but the tag says MS-Access. They are different. Which one are you using?

Comment: What is your criteria for generating the output you have shown? For product A, you are showing a lowest price of 10 and a highest discount of 4. But why not show a highest discount of 5? And which region do you want to show based on these criteria? As written, this is impossible to answer without clarification on your rules for our outcome.

Comment: MS Access. Sorry, I have thought they are some kind of similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are trying to find the lowest price for each product first, and then for *that product name and price*, what is the highest discount.  This should do it.

```
SELECT A.ProductName,
    A.MinOfPrice,
    B.MaxOfDiscount
FROM (SELECT P.productName,
        MIN(P.price) AS MinOfprice
    FROM Product as P
    GROUP BY P.productName)
    AS A
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT P.productName,
        P.Price,
        MAX(P.Discount) AS MaxOfDiscount
    FROM Product as P
    GROUP BY P.productName,
        P.Price)
    AS B
ON  A.ProductName = B.ProductName AND
    A.MinOfPrice = B.Price
```

Answer (score 0):

If I don't get you wrong, you should use the MIN and MAX functions, and you can use both in the same statement.

```
SELECT MIN(A.price), MAX(A.discount)
FROM Product A
```

Comment: I could but then the result would be A, 10, 5 for the first row. Should be A, 10, 4 because they cannot be treated independently.